# Flutter return Firestore array values to a List

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Flutter table calendar plugin to make a calendar. In order to put events into the calendar, I have to add data to _events map. I want to get the data from Firestore document, and put the data into _events map. However, I don't know how to do it. I search everywhere but I can't get an answer.

This is my code

```
class _MemberEventsState extends State<MemberEvents>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List _selectedEvents;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  CalendarController _calendarController;
  List<String> list = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('events')
        .document('2019-07-30')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      list = List.from(ds['title']);
    });

    _events = {DateTime.parse("2019-08-01"): list};
    _selectedEvents = _events[_selectedDay] ?? [];
    _calendarController = CalendarController();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onDaySelected');
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = events;
    });
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildTableCalendar(),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Expanded(child: _buildEventList()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
    return TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        selectedColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
        todayColor: Colors.blueAccent[200],
        markersColor: Colors.brown[700],
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        formatButtonTextStyle:
            TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
      onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventList() {
    return ListView(
      children: _selectedEvents
          .map((event) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(event.toString()),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

So in the first step to achieve my goal, I made a document named 2019-07-30, then I made an array in it named title. Then I tried to get the values in the array to a List named list. However, list returned null.

I don't know where I went wrong.

I am new to Flutter, so the question might seem stupid.

Also, I am new to stackoverflow, so if I did any steps wrong on describing the question, please tell me so I can fix it.

[image: This is my Firestore data]

Comment: Is the variable ds filled with data, if so what returns ds['title']? If you have trouble I suggest following a tutorial like [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/using-firebases-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-79a79ec5303a)

Comment: I am using that method, but it return null

Comment: Yes but the tutorial contains a StreamBuilder which can help you get the data from Firebase